# flutter: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, dio

I created an app and test it on emulator and andriod phone, i am using api's and nodejs based backend and mongodb database. it works fine when i test it on devices, but when i run it on chrome it sends me this error.

**Error:**

```
Error: Unsupported operation: NetworkInterface.list

DioError [DioErrorType.response]: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

here is my dio request code

**Code:**

```
calltimeInApi() async {
    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': getname,
      'token': getaccesstoken,
      
    };
    timeOutButtonPressed=true;
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrlTimeIn,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse)async {
       
        getapitimein=onResponse.data['TimeIn'];


      }).catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
    });
  }
```

please help where i am doing wrong!

Comment: is it returning `cors` error on the inspect devtool on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any issues on the code snippet that you've shared. If the HTTP Requests works fine on mobile devices but not on web, I suggest check the logs if you're getting CORS errors. A quick workaround on this issue is by running the web app with html renderer in debug.

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```